# Passport-jwt different tokens same result

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm having a problem setting up my first project using passport and jwt. Using Postman I tried to sign in with different accounts but if I try to return the `req.user` object, it returns the same user's infos. otherwise, if I try to log `jwt_payload` it's right (different user's information). Can anyone explain me why? (I insert the option `session: false`)

my jwt strategy function:

```
var confStrategy = function(passport) {
  passport.use( new JwtStrategy( opts, function(jwt_payload,done) {
      User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub},function(err,user) {

          if(err) return done(err,none);
          if(user) {
            done(null,user);
          } else {
            done(null,false);
          }
      });
  }));
};
```

the app.js snippet

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
passConf.confStrategy(passport);

app.get('/api/:name',passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.user);
  res.send('Hello ' + req.user.email);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In passport middleware, edit the line of `JwtStrategy`:

From:

```
{id: jwt_payload.sub}
```

To:

```
{_id: jwt_payload._doc._id}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem! The code below worked for me.

```
module.exports = function(passport) {  ;
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
 User.findById(jwt_payload._id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }
    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false);
    }
  });
 }));
};
```

The problem lies with User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the code that generates JWT token, whatever payload you set during JWT generation time. You will get same Payload with same name when JWTStrategy decode's it. (as you are getting same user every time, check if it is hard coded or not)

Below line generates JWT token

```
var token = jwt.sign({uid: user.id}, secretOrKey, {expiresIn: 6000});
```

Below is the JWT strategy code.

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(_payload, _next) {
  var done = false;
  if((_payload.uid)) {
   //Do something 
  }
}));
```

You need to keep the name same (in above case it is `uid`)